# Cannot install bluetooth-indicator, ubuntu-desktop or unity-control-center

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

Messages pertain to incompatible dependencies. I do have back-up though. How do i go about it? Currently the control (gear icon pertaining also to system-settings) hardly functions (except for shut-down).
I have also used the following:

```
1. dpkg --list | grep ^rc
2. sudo dpkg --purge `dpkg --get-selections | awk '/deinstall/ {print $1}'
3. sudo apt-get clean, autoclean, autoremove
4. sudo apt-get update
5. sudo apt-get upgrade
```

Thank you for your suggestions.

Comment: It'd be great if you could post the issues you're having with incompatible dependencies.

Comment: @codingman This was the problem. The messages were simply 'dependencies' incompatible with this or that packet. And i culd not know which packet to install first. Luckily after gsettings reset com.canonical.Unity.Devices blacklist and restoring i have 'somehow' now the state where system settings etc are available.

Answer (score 1):

All the messages were simply dependencies incompatible with this or that packet. I could not know which packet to install first. Luckily after `gsettings reset com.canonical.Unity.Devices blacklist` and restoring I have the state where system settings etc are available.

Comment: By my comment I meant if you could post the output to a pastie or the like, but I guess since you fixed it it's fine.